# Proof with conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ random variables IID with $\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)=pq^{x}$. Show that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left.X=x\right|X+Y=n\right)=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$$

for $x=0,1,...,n$.

Hint: If $X,Y$ are two random variables independent then

$$\mathbb{P}\left(Z=z\right)=\sum_{x}\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=z-x\right)$$

where $Z=X+Y$.

My attempt:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left.X=x\right|X+Y=n\right)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}\left(X=x,X+Y=n\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X+Y=n\right)}=$$

$$=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}\left(X=x,Y=n-x\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X+Y=n\right)}=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}\left(X=x\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=n-x\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X+Y=n\right)}=...$$

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
P(X=x)P(Y=n-x)=pq^x(pq^{n-x})=p^2q^n \quad (0\leq x\leq n)
$$
while
$$
P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{x=0}^nP(X=x)P(Y=n-x)=p^2q^n(n+1)
$$
whence
$$
\frac{P(X=x)P(Y=n-x)}{P(X+Y=n)}=\frac{1}{n+1};\quad (0\leq x\leq n).
$$